# Defined a window as a class, but unable to call mainloop function

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am so trash at coding that I have no idea how to utilise classes to make cool stuff :( --- I'm really new to GUI development, and I'm trying to make a simple maze game with a level selector. I have the maze program squared away, but I am somehow hopeless at Tkinter apparently, since I've been trying constantly for the last hour to find a solution online. As you might have noticed, this is my first post here.

I'm running this in PyCharm, using my decent computer on Windows 10. I'm especially trash at this IDE since I, for some reason, cannot install any libraries/ use any libraries that I see clearly installed in my list of libraries... but that's for another post. As I've mentioned, I've been trying to figure out a simple program for the past hour, but nothing seems to be working.

Nothing I find online is particularly useful, either, and the ones that might be are so hopelessly complex that I cannot understand what they are trying to achieve. I'm looking for a simple solution to a simple problem, and hopefully, this great community can help me out.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        self = tk.Tk()
        self.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (1920,1080))


root = Window()

root.mainloop()
```

Expected: Window appears
Observed: Program abruptly ends

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/(GD) ShadowPlague/PycharmProjects/GameDesign/Main.py", line 12, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'mainloop'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create class in wrong way. You can't assign `Tk()` to `self` to create correctly class. External `root` will have nothing to do with internal `self`. First you create instance `Window()` and assign to variable `root` but later you create instance `Tk()` and assign to `self` but it will not change instance assigned to `root`.

---

First method: create `Tk()` inside class as `self.root` and then you use `win.root`

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (1920,1080))

win = Window()

win.root.mainloop()
```

Second method: inherit from `Tk()`. It needs `Window(tk.Tk)` and `super().__init__`

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (1920,1080))

root = Window()

root.mainloop()
```